# save all links in html page to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

i really need help regarding importing a webpage to pdf at client side without using chrome pdf save api. This HTML page is being generated through a desktop application and My page contain frames and one frame shows html file according to link clicked, So is there any possible ways to import all links html along with images. 
jsPDF is working fine but with the text and images i need to align manually, like for each and every image it would be hectic, so is there any way to import html to pdf with all links.

Comment: It looks like you can specify a certain HTML element to use for generating the PDF. So can you just make a new element in the document, copy all the elements you need (or inject HTML) into it, and then generate the PDF from that?

Comment: yes, i am going to use a specified button and onclick i m going the bind the event to generate pdf, but the main problem is i am not using server, its a desktop application generating html so if someone will use it , i cant expect them to go online and convert the page to pdf.